# 500 internal server error when writing file to the server

Tags: android, asp.net, file-upload, xamarin

I'm developing an android app with Xamarin that uploads file to the server. My server is asp.net based and is hosted by azure. Xamarin throws this error when the code tries to write the file to the server directory. The code I'm using to post the file to the server is as follows:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
    {
        videoThumbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var progress = new System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler();

        progress.HttpSendProgress += progress_HttpSendProgress;

        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalVariables.host);

            // Set the Accept header for BSON.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

            var request = new uploadFileModel { data = file, dateCreated = DateTime.Now, fileName = fileName, username = loggedUser, VideoThumbName = videoThumbName};

            // POST using the BSON formatter.
            MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            var m = client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize;
            var result = await client.PostAsync("api/media/upload", request, bsonFormatter);

            return result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

I've tried using a try catch block and the weird thing is that the exception is caught even after the file has been written to the path and I get the 500 internal server error. So far every file I tried to upload was save to the path but I can't figure out why is error occurring.

My server side code looks like the following:

```
       [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload(uploadFileModel model)
    {


        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string thumbname = "";
            string resizedthumbname = Guid.NewGuid() + "_yt.jpg";

            string FfmpegPath = Encoding_Settings.FFMPEGPATH;

            string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempuploads"), model.fileName);
            string pathToFiles = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempuploads");
            string pathToThumbs = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/thumbs");
            string finalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/contents/member/" + model.username + "/flv");
            string resizedthumb = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, resizedthumbname);


            var outputPathVid = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(finalPath, model.fileName) };
            var inputPathVid = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(pathToFiles, model.fileName) };
            int maxWidth = 380;
            int maxHeight = 360;

            var namewithoutext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.Combine(pathToFiles, model.fileName));
            thumbname = model.VideoThumbName;
            string oldthumbpath = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname);


            var fileName = model.fileName;
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, model.data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }



            if (model.fileName.Contains("audio"))
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(finalPath, model.fileName), model.data);

                string audio_thumb = "mic_thumb.jpg";
                string destination = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, audio_thumb);
                string source = Path.Combine(pathToFiles, audio_thumb);
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(destination))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, true);
                }


                Video_Struct vd = new Video_Struct();
                vd.CategoryID = 0; // store categoryname or term instead of category id
                vd.Categories = "";
                vd.UserName = model.username;
                vd.Title = "";
                vd.Description = "";
                vd.Tags = "";
                vd.OriginalVideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.VideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.ThumbFileName = "mic_thumb.jpg";
                vd.isPrivate = 0;
                vd.AuthKey = "";
                vd.isEnabled = 1;
                vd.Response_VideoID = 0; // video responses
                vd.isResponse = 0;
                vd.isPublished = 1;
                vd.isReviewed = 1;
                vd.Thumb_Url = "none";
                //vd.FLV_Url = flv_url;
                vd.Embed_Script = "";
                vd.isExternal = 0; // website own video, 1: embed video
                vd.Type = 0;
                vd.YoutubeID = "";
                vd.isTagsreViewed = 1;
                vd.Mode = 0; // filter videos based on website sections
                long videoid = VideoBLL.Process_Info(vd, false);
            }
```

The exception doesn't reveal much for me to understand the issue. Strangely I don't get any errors when I'm sending request to the local server. Any idea what might be wrong here?

**Edit:**

The exception no longer occurring when I get the internal server error at this line of my code `using (var engine = new Engine())` This is a library I'm trying to use to encode a media file. If everything works on the local server then why doesn't it on the live server :/

```
using (var engine = new Engine())
                {
                    engine.GetMetadata(inputPathVid);

                    // Saves the frame located on the 15th second of the video.
                    var outputPathThumb = new MediaFile { Filename = Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+".jpg") };
                    var options = new ConversionOptions { Seek = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), CustomHeight = 360, CustomWidth = 380 };
                    engine.GetThumbnail(inputPathVid, outputPathThumb, options);

                }

                Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+".jpg"));

                //var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
                //var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
                //var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

                var newWidth = (int)(maxWidth);
                var newHeight = (int)(maxHeight);

                var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);
                bmp.Save(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname+"_resized.jpg"));

                //File.Delete(Path.Combine(pathToThumbs, thumbname));

                using (var engine = new Engine())
                {

                    var conversionOptions = new ConversionOptions
                    {
                        VideoSize = VideoSize.Hd720,
                        AudioSampleRate = AudioSampleRate.Hz44100,
                        VideoAspectRatio = VideoAspectRatio.Default
                    };

                    engine.GetMetadata(inputPathVid);
                    engine.Convert(inputPathVid, outputPathVid, conversionOptions);

                }

                File.Delete(tempFilePath);

                Video_Struct vd = new Video_Struct();
                vd.CategoryID = 0; // store categoryname or term instead of category id
                vd.Categories = "";
                vd.UserName = model.username;
                vd.Title = "";
                vd.Description = "";
                vd.Tags = "";
                vd.Duration = inputPathVid.Metadata.Duration.ToString();
                vd.Duration_Sec = Convert.ToInt32(inputPathVid.Metadata.Duration.Seconds.ToString());
                vd.OriginalVideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.VideoFileName = model.fileName;
                vd.ThumbFileName = thumbname+"_resized.jpg";
                vd.isPrivate = 0;
                vd.AuthKey = "";
                vd.isEnabled = 1;
                vd.Response_VideoID = 0; // video responses
                vd.isResponse = 0;
                vd.isPublished = 1;
                vd.isReviewed = 1;
                vd.Thumb_Url = "none";
                //vd.FLV_Url = flv_url;
                vd.Embed_Script = "";
                vd.isExternal = 0; // website own video, 1: embed video
                vd.Type = 0;
                vd.YoutubeID = "";
                vd.isTagsreViewed = 1;
                vd.Mode = 0; // filter videos based on website sections
                //vd.ContentLength = f_contentlength;
                vd.GalleryID = 0;
                long videoid = VideoBLL.Process_Info(vd, false);

            }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Are the memory exhausted on the remote server?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm only hosting one app on my azure server. I would get some kinda warning to notify if my memory was being exhausted

Comment: Do you  `return result`? what is the e.message printing?

Comment: What is the actual exception you are getting?  500 is just a general HTTP status code, it alone doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: I've changed the path to write the file and the exception is no longer occurring but I get the error now at this line using (var engine = new Engine()). It's an encoder library I;m using to encode media file in my server side.  I don't know why I'm getting the error. Being a coder is extremely frustrating :(

Comment: You keep saying you're getting an exception, but you never tell us what it is.  Knowing the actual exception is pretty key to figuring out the problem.  As I noted earlier, 500 itself is not meaningful.

Comment: The exception said _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699 when I was trying to write file to the path. The path didn't exist on the server so I manually created it. I figured it might be due to that so I changed the output destination to a path that already existed. Doing so, I don't get that exception anymore but the Xamarin debugger abruptly stops at that line I mentioned in my previous post and issues the errir message when the debugger on the server hits that line

Comment: I have pasted the full server side code here http://pastebin.com/SveMPaU1

Comment: What library are you using for encoding?  I'm not an Azure expert but there are a lot of restrictions it places on what it will run.  It would not surprise me if a COM+ DLL would not work on an Azure hosted site

Comment: I'm using a NuGet library I found here https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/1.0.0.3

Comment: that looks ok - again, not an Azure expert.  But you really need to look at the logs to figure out what is happening.